# Como filtro por un campo en una relacion muchos a muchos en Elequent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

Tengo una consulta, estoy codificando en Laravel 5, utilice Eloquent como ORM, tengo una duda la cual tengo días intentando resolver, agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar:

tengo 2 tablas las cuales tienen una relacion M:M y necesito filtrar el resultado por un campo de una de las tablas.

las tablas son las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo necesito hace una consulta para saber cuantas hojas de vidas han sido vistas, otra para saber cuales se han descargado y cuales han sido descargadas, y de esas debe ser filtrada por el campo dominio de la tabla hojas_vida.

el código que tengo actualmente para el caso de no vistas funciona pero no filtra.

Este es el código que tengo en el modelo HojaVida y me retorna las hojas de vida

```
public function vistas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Empleado::class,'empleado_hv_vista','hojavida_id','empleado_id');
}
```

Aqui el código que tengo en el controlador ReporteController

```
$vistas = HojaVida::whereHas('vistas', function ($query) {
      $query->where('empleados.empresa_id', $this->empresa->id);
    })->count();
```

Esto me lista las hojas de vida vistas para cada empresa, solo debo filtrar por dominio y por empresa

```
$no_vistas = HojaVida::WheredoesntHave('vistas')->count();
```

Y este otro código me muestra las hojas de vida que no han sido vista, sin embargo no filtra ni por empresa ni dominio...

quien me puede ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes concatenar mas filtros a las consultas. Por ejemplo en la ultima podrías:

$no_vistas = HojaVida::WheredoesntHave('vistas')->where('dominio', "DominioParaFiltrar")->count();

Comment: Si asi logre resolver el detalle, muchas gracias.